# blogging app - how to save formatted text and images

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm starting to work on a blogging app. My question is how do I save the formatted text so that it can be displayed the way it was formatted. For instance, if the editor marks a word as bold, how do I save that information so that it can be displayed as a bold text? In other words, how do I save the dynamically generated css?

Comment: This is fairly broad - likely lots of ways to do this. But there are some fairly standard ways of representing formatted content, such as markdown. How you go about doing so, though, is really up to you.

Comment: That would all depend on the editor you're using or how you decide to format the editor.

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm trying to build something similar to https://medium.com/ where someone can create content. @NewToJS It's not clear what you mean by editor.

Comment: @DavidMakogon thanks David. If I want to build a blogging platform like www.medium.com, do you think markdown would be the right way to represent the content? I'm just trying to get an idea of what technology I should should use to build such a platform.

Comment: Like I said: it's up to you. I can't tell you what technology to use.

Comment: @DavidMakogon So I did a bit of search and stumbled on ghost.js Is this something I can use to build a blogging platform? I'm completely new to this technology and hence my questions are very naive. Thanks again. I'm just trying to understand what technology should I focus on.

Comment: @quantdaddy It's down to you to do the research and decide if the plug-ins you find will be useful to use on your blogging platform. So this means reading the documentation to see if it offered features/functionality that you're looking for and then look at the demos/example source code to see if you think it's something you will be able to use. StackOverflow is for people with specific programming issues, not to seek recommendation for software/plug-ins or tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. One way I might approach this is to save the post content in a format like [Markdown](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax). Then you need to use a Markdown to HTML converter that will generate the HTML and CSS for you. Alternatively, you could implement some custom formatting rules of your own, or use an open source WYSIWYG editor that might have a plugin to export to HTML that you can save.

Comment: Do you think markdown format would be enough to create content as in https://medium.com/ ?

Comment: Markdown is good for simple static content like headings, body text, images, links, and formatting like bold and italics. You'll have to look at the Markdown website and evaluate if it meets your needs. It starts to fall short when you need greater layout control or richer content types like tables or embedded video players.